# MySQL connection fails with one database and not the other

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have 2 databases on mysql. **ge** and **ge_sc001.**

I can access both of these through my asp.net mvc application locally.

**Web.config**

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="GEContext_sc001" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=***;database=ge_sc001" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="GEContext_sc002" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=***;database=ge" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="GEContext" connectionString="server=localhost;port=3306;uid=root;pwd=***;database=ge" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Later on when i deployed my application on the web server, and tried to access them from a remote machine. I changed **server=localhost** to my machine's external-facing IP address. Now I can access only one **ge**. when i try to access the second it gives me error.

> Access denied for user 'root'@'' to database 'ge_sc001'

Notice there is no localhost above i.e. 'root'@'localhost'

**SHOW GRANTS**

'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON . TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD \'*xxx\' WITH GRANT OPTION' 'GRANT PROXY ON \'\'@\'\' TO \'root\'@\'localhost\' WITH GRANT OPTION'

### UPDATE

I ran

```
GRANT ALL ON ge_sc001.* TO 'root'@'<external_ip>';
```

Now the error has change to

> The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.

This is now happening on both of my schemas

Comment: Is the port forwarded on your router? Is your pc's firewall allowing connections on that port? Does root have permission from any host for the db ge?

Comment: Do _not_ use `root` as the "user" for applications.

Answer (score 0):

There was an extra entry in mysql.user table with host as '' that was interfering. Deleted it manually and running FLUSH PRIVILEGES worked for me.